# Dynamic query execution in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, mysql-workbench, .net-core-2.2

I am developing a hospitality domain application (.Net Core 2.2) in which i am developing a reporting module. From a dashboard few filters are available to fetch records from Data Base.

Below is the DTO i am using to contains filters

```
public class SearchDto
{
    public DateTime DateForm {get;set;}
    public DateTime DateTo {get;set;}
    public DateSearchType SearchType {get;set;}
    public string RegionId {get;set;}
    public OrdersStatus status {get;set;}
    public string PaymentModeTypes {get;set;}
    public string channel {get;set;}
}
```

Here DateSearchType  is a enum with value

1. Start // service Start Date
2. End   // service End Date
3. Creation // Order Creation Date

Also OrdersStatus (an enum) with values like All , Confirmed , Cancelled , PaymnetFailed etc

PaymentModeTypes can be a single string or comma seprated string for ex : "NetBanking, CreditCard, DebitCard, Cash"

RegionId is also a single string or comma seprated string as "101, 102, 102"

Same for Channel either "Web" or "Web, Mobile"

Curently ef core expressssion i am using is as follow

```
var v = Database.Orders.List(
              x => ((SearchType == DateSearchType.Start) ? x.Services.Any(y => (y.MinStartTime >= DateForm.Date && y.MinStartTime <= DateTo.Date)) || DateForm.Date.Equals(DateTime.MinValue) : true)
              && ((SearchType == DateSearchType.End) ? x.Services.Any(y => y.MaxEndTime >= DateForm.Date && y.MaxEndTime <= DateTo.Date) : true)
              && ((SearchType == DateSearchType.Creation) ? x.BookingDate.Date >= DateForm.Date && x.BookingDate.Date <= DateTo.Date : true)
              && (RegionId.Length == 0 || RegionId.Contains(x.RegionId))
              && (status == OrdersStatus.All || x.Status == status)
              && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PaymentModeTypes) || PaymentTypes.Contains(x.PaymentType))
              && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(channel) || channels.Contains(x.ChannelName)), //Where
                     x => x.Guests, 
                     x => x.Services 
                     );
```

Here Guests and Services are two another tables set as navigation property in Orders Model

This expression is working fine but taking too much time to execute , any good approach to optimize it or right way to rewrite this code ?

Also what is the best practice to exclude any filter if its value is not provided.

Few Filters are not mandatory, they can be supplied or not, so query execution has to be of dynamic nature. current implementation if a filter value is not supplied

```
 && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PaymentModeTypes) || PaymentTypes.Contains(x.PaymentType))
```

Can anybody suggest some good material or any piece of code regarding this so i can optimize it.

Please ignore Typo as i am not habitual to use dark theme

Edit 1:Client Evaluation set as off

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder
            .ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning));
    }
```

Comment: Does the filter translate to SQL or evaluate in memory?

Comment: it is running on MySql Data Base , not on in memory collection

Comment: True, but you are using EF Core 2.x which supports the so called "client evaluation". So to make sure the filtering happens in database, turn client evaluation off as shown here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#previous-versions. This is the first thing to check. Please confirm that first, then you we can think if the query can be optimized.

Comment: it is not configured in my DB Context so i guess by default its on , set it off see edit 1:

Comment: Hello @IvanStoev any suggestion now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some inefficiency in the generated SQL which might be causing the performance issue.

Before EF Core one is expected to conditionally chain multiple `Where` calls or use some predicate builder utility to build conditionally `Where` predicate having only the necessary conditions.

This normally is not needed in EF Core, because it tries to automatically eliminate such conditions. It does that for logical expressions (`||` , `&&`), but failing to do so for the conditional expressions (`? :`). So the solution is to replace the later with the equivalent logical expressions.

You are doing that for most of your conditions, but not for the first 3. So replace

```
x => ((SearchType == DateSearchType.Start) ? x.Services.Any(y => (y.MinStartTime >= DateForm.Date && y.MinStartTime <= DateTo.Date)) || DateForm.Date.Equals(DateTime.MinValue) : true)
    && ((SearchType == DateSearchType.End) ? x.Services.Any(y => y.MaxEndTime >= DateForm.Date && y.MaxEndTime <= DateTo.Date) : true)
    && ((SearchType == DateSearchType.Creation) ? x.BookingDate.Date >= DateForm.Date && x.BookingDate.Date <= DateTo.Date : true)
```

with

```
x => (SearchType != DateSearchType.Start || x.Services.Any(y => y.MinStartTime >= DateForm.Date && y.MinStartTime <= DateTo.Date) || DateForm.Date.Equals(DateTime.MinValue))
    && (SearchType != DateSearchType.End || x.Services.Any(y => y.MaxEndTime >= DateForm.Date && y.MaxEndTime <= DateTo.Date))
    && (SearchType != DateSearchType.Creation || x.BookingDate.Date >= DateForm.Date && x.BookingDate.Date <= DateTo.Date)
```

and see if that helps. For sure the generated SQL will be optimal.

---

Noticed that you are using different variable names for comma separated strings and `Contains` filters. So I'm assuming you have something like this

```
public IEnumerable<string> PaymentTypes => (PaymentModeTypes ?? "").Split(", ");
public IEnumerable<string> channels => (channel ?? "").Split(", ");
```

which is good and will generate SQL `IN (...)` conditions when necessary.

You might consider doing the same for regions, e.g. add

```
public IEnumerable<string> RegionIds => (RegionId ?? "").Split(", ");
```

and replace

```
&& (RegionId.Length == 0 || RegionId.Contains(x.RegionId))
```

with

```
&& (string.IsNullOrEmpty(RegionId) || RegionIds.Contains(x.RegionId))
```